# Почему сокет не выбрасывает ошибку при отправке, когда сеть разорвана?

Tags: python, tcp

Компьютер и распбери соеденины посредством wi-fi роутера. На одном устройстве tcp-сервер, на другом tcp-клиент. Если выдернуть питание из роутера, (сэмулировав таким образом потерю связи), то функция `send` мало того что не генерирует исключение, она продолжает возвращать ненулевое значение еще очень долго (я не дождался ошибки), якобы данные были отправлены (куда? кому?). Я пробовал как вторую версию python так и третью. Менял клиент и сервер местами. Выглядит так, будто-то это нормальное поведение. Но как тогда обнаружить потерю связи?

Код клиента примерно такой:

```
tcp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcp_socket.connect(addr)

while True:
    try:
       sent = tcp_socket.send(b'data')
       print(sent) 
    except:
        print("cant send") 
        break

    time.sleep(2)

tcp_socket.close()
```

Comment: а Вы хотите моментально получать ошибку? Это почти не возможно. Но если в протокол внесете возможность подтверждать отправку, тогда да, все будет

Comment: @KoVadim А разве TCP не должен дожидаться подтверждения получения? Это же не UDP сокет.

Comment: он дожидается. но если бы он дожидался каждый пакет, то скорость бы была очень низкой

Comment: А с другой стороны подумайте, ну вот не приходит подтверждение, сколько ждать? Секунду, минуту, час? Поэтому tcp напихает пачкой пакеты, а потом может и подтвердить пачкой

Comment: Нормальное время ожидания в tcp  2 часа. В принципе, его можно изменить, как для системы в целом, так и (в Линуксе) для отдельного соединения (см. man setsockopt и man 7 tcp)